# Capture right-click'd text on Outlook Message Content

Tags: vba, outlook

I'd like to know if it's possible to capture the text when a user right-click's on an Outlook message, and then add items to the right-click menu depending on the type of text.

This is an example of what I'd like to do.  If there's a message (mail item) with the following content:  "Hello, please call me at 555-8474 regarding item A1234" and the user right-click's on the number "8", the pop-up context menu will have an extra item at the bottom called "Call 555-8474", and a "PhoneCall" sub will be run if selected.  If the user right-click's anywhere on "A1234" a different item (i.e. "Look up A1234") will be shown.

We're running Outlook 2003 and if possible I'd like to know if this can be done using VBA.  I'm open to other ideas as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this example](http://www.outlookcode.com/codedetail.aspx?id=1635) in VBA to get started

Comment: Alejandro, Thanks, your answer helps, but only with the modfication of the right click context menu. I'm still having trouble figuring out if it's at all possible to capture the actual word that was right click'd. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SmartTags is an Office 2003 feature that was designed for exactly this sort of thing.  I honestly don't know SmartTags well enough to do more than wave in the general direction, so I hope you get a better answer from a domain expert....